# how work routing in "asp.net core web application"

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I created a new "asp.net core web application" project. NOT MVC!.

i see in the stratup.cs, in configure method:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

question a: the url mapped directly to razor pages ('/Index' => /Pages/Index.cshtml). and there is no IController in the entire project, **What the routing of MVC doing here?**

quetstion b: if i want additionaly custom routing, can I do this without turn all routing to MVC methodology?

Comment: answers to both questions exist in documentation: [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing) and [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: you can probably use attribute routing too

Comment: you can remove the `routes.MapRoute` part and pages will still work

Comment: @Shyju so its a mistake of the template developers?

Answer (score 1):

Razor pages are a feature of ASP.Net MVC, hence the dependency on certain services and middleware, but they offer a lightweight alternative to the traditional Model-Controller-View approach.  A Razor view represents the View and a code-behind class represents the Model and Controller.

By convention:

```
/Pages/Index.cshtml routes to / or /Index
/Pages/Contact.cshtml routes to /Contact
/Pages/Store/Contact.cshtml routes to /Store/Contact
```

For a full answer, you should probably read the documentation.

Comment: thank! but i'm not fund any official documentation for this convention.